# How to retrieve form data sent over HTTPS in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, https

I'm a bit of a back-end security n00b, so please be gentle if I'm missing something obvious:

When I get values over HTTP in node, the form data is in the request object `req.body.{name of input element}`

Over HTTPS, `req.body` doesn't seem to exist. I've tried logging out the `req` object but I can't see it anywhere in there. What am I doing wrong?

```
function checkUser(req, res) {
    console.dir(req);
    //if passwords don't match
    if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirm_password) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {

    if (checkUser(req, res)) {
        createUser(req, res)
        res.redirect('/browse?p=0');
    }
    res.render('register', {
        error: 'Passwords did not match'
    })
});
```

As soon as it goes to the checkUser method it crashes saying that req.body is not defined. So where is the data kept?

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks

James

Comment: Are you `use`ing the `bodyParser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it...

I'd called things in the right order, but I'd included all the passportjs stuff (and the corresponding middlewares) in a module file. Because of probably scope or race conditions it didn't register the middleware before the route and controller were executed.

in web.js:

```
app = express();
app.settings.env = 'development';
app.engine('dust', dustjs.dust({
    cache: false
}));
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '\\views');

//Middleware
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico', {
    maxAge: 2592000000
}));

app.use(app.router);

//Environment Variables
//app.configure('development', function() {
app.use(express.errorHandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
}));
dustjs.isDebug = true;


auth = require('./modules/auth/auth').auth(app);
```

in auth.js

```
module.exports.auth = function(app) {
//verification using passport.js
passport = require("passport");
express = require('express');
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'SECRET'
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` only exists if you link in the appropriate middleware to parse the request body.  I recommend the following:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
```

You often see `express.bodyParser()` being used, but I recommend avoiding this because it also includes `express.multipart()`, which has been deprecated, and will disappear when Express updates its dependency on Connect.  If you need to parse multipart form data, look into [Busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy) or [Formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable).

I don't think your issue has anything to do with HTTPS: parsing the request body is the same process in HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Hi @Ethan Brown, yes I'm using bodyParser...

I'll swap them out and try again....

Comment: In addition, be sure to register those middlewares before any routes that depend on them.

Comment: Hm...if you're using `bodyParser` the `req.body` object should be available...so I wonder if Ray's not on to something (you're linking it in the wrong place).  It should be one of the first middlewares that gets linked in....

Comment: Thanks Ethan, @RayStantz was onto something... see below! :)